# how to create a mind-map based tree-view windows based application in .NET

Tags: .net, wpf, user-controls, treeview, mindmapping

I'm looking to create an intuitive tree-view structure (on the similar lines of a Mind-map) for my .NET Windows Application (WPF).

Something on the similar lines as [this](http://vivamind.net/maps/detail/70) or [this](http://www.spicynodes.org/)

I'm initially planning to develop a sample application, wherein my application just reads an underlying structured XML to create a mind-map like visualization and display it to the user. The user can select any of the displayed tree node. If the node has child nodes, it shall be displayed when the user clicks on the corresponding parent node.

To achieve this i need a heads up or help in the right direction to begin with. Any help is deeply appreciated

Comment: Are you allowed to use a commercial library?  If so check out  http://www.nwoods.com/components/silverlight-wpf/goxam-overview.htm

Comment: Hi Josh ..thanks for your input.I can definitely use a commercially available alternative, but i was more interested in developing the same and so i require some inputs in the direction of "where to start.." etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a network map from scratch before in WPF but not a Mind Map.  It's not easy and would take a few pages to explain every step.  So I've given a quick startup below on how I accomplished my network map.  I don't think there would be much difference other than the layout and the visual representation of the nodes and node connectors.

The first place to start is your collection.  MSDN has a killer Directed Graph collection available here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379574(v=vs.80).aspx.

After your collection is established, you will need to extend the Panel class so it can perform your layout for you.  I don't know of any existing Mind Map layout panels, but here's a link to a Radial Panel layout:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771363(v=vs.90).aspx.  It should show you the steps required to place things in a custom layout.

You will also need a way to visually represent your directed graph nodes.  The beautiful thing about WPF is you can create your own UserControls and if your panel is created to layout properly, it will perform all the layout work for your custom controls.  My network map was simply a UserControl with an ellipse as the background, thrown into a Radial Panel.

The final step is the ability to examine your graph collection and draw the connectors between connected nodes.  In my directed graph collection I added a property of type object called Tag and I stored the UserControl version of the node.  This way I know the coordinates of the connected UserControls and I can connect them with a PolyLine.  I think the difference for you is you would want your connector as Image.

That's the quick version.  I'd love to post source code here that shows more, but I wrote it for work and they would kill me.

Comment: your last sentence sounds funny :-) Can you make a rough estimate about the effort required to build some simple prototype?